# PHP variable from HTML text input

Tags: php, variables, input

I'm having trouble setting a HTML input text into a PHP variable `$x`. If I set `$x` to an image URL, my code seems to work. Now I want the user to input an URL instead of myself. I've tried using `[value = "<？$x ？> ]` and other variations of this inside of the input text tag but they didn't work. I've also tried using `$image_source` (my input name) inside of my PHP tags, but I just get errors instead.

I do not have a submit button because it refreshes my page, negating the PHP echo, so I changed it to a button. How can I put the user's input into a variable so that I can use it inside of my php tags?

```
<body>
    <form action = "metadata.php" method = "post" id = "meta_form">
        <input type = "text" name = "image_source" id = "image_source" />
        <input type = "button" value = "Check" id ="submit_button" onclick = "check();"/>
    </form>
    <?php
        $photo_data = exif_read_data($x);
        echo $photo_data['FileName'];
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `$x = $_POST['image_source'];` to your PHP script? You should also keep your submit button, if not nothing will be sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Marcelo's answer, it looks like you are not accessing the POST variable correctly.

If you are using `$image_source` to get the POST data, you will require [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) to be enabled on the server.

As stated in the PHP Manual, it is highly recommended not to use this featuere due to security concerns as well as the feature is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 5.4

In your case, you would want to use `$_POST['image_source']` (alternatively `$_REQUEST['image_source']`) to access the POST data for that text box.

If you are having further issues, check to see that your usage of [`exif_read_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) is correct or if there is any error checking / validation checking you want to perform before echoing it.